# Excel - Replace Google's Drive hyperlinks with local folder paths

Tags: excel, drive

I have an Excel doc with Google's drive hyperlinks to photos, I want to change these to link local photos I downloaded in a folder instead. Is this possible without having to do it manually ?

Hyperlink : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yCSptfKRkbkN39Lkbz2yXLM0CI332_DC

Image name : _storage_emulated_0_odk_instances_CASA_2018-06-22_15-29-52_1529678182622.jpg

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: With your update to the question, a slightly more involved method is needed. Please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you are using shareable links from Google drive - this means that the filename of the images is not visible in the link, and hence you need to uncover the filename by opening the link. We can do this in VBA by invoking a browser object, here, using Internet Explorer:

```
Sub GetFileName()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yCSptfKRkbkN39Lkbz2yXLM0CI332_DC"
    While ie.busy = True 'Allow the website to load
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Wend

    Debug.Print (ie.Document.Title)
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

This gets us the filename `/storage/emulated/0/odk/instances/CASA_2018-06-22_15-29-52/1529678182622.jpg` for the link you have. As you have stated that the filename on your computer is: `_storage_emulated_0_odk_instances_CASA_2018-06-22_15-29-52_1529678182622.jpg`, we replace `\` with `_` using the `replace`-function. We will also need to remove the " - Google Disk" text from the end of the filename:

```
Sub GetFileName()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim fname As String 'Saving filename as string for later use
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    ie.Navigate "https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yCSptfKRkbkN39Lkbz2yXLM0CI332_DC"
    While ie.busy = True 'Allow the website to load the image (wait for 1 second if browser is busy)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Wend
    fname = ie.Document.Title
    ie.Quit
    fname = Replace(fname, "/", "_") 'Changing filename to fit your local file
    fname = Replace(fname, " - Google Disk", "") 'Removing the additional text from the filename
    Debug.Print (fname)
End Sub
```

Now that we have that working, we can loop through the region in your excel sheet where you have the hyperlinks saved. We will also make sure that Excel recognises the paths to the local file as a hyperlink, using `Hyperlinks.Add`:

```
Sub GetFileName()
    Dim ie As Object
    Dim fname As String, wlink As String, lpath As String
    lpath = "C:\Users\LocalAccount\Downloads\" 'The folder where you have the images saved
    Set ie = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.Application")
    For i = 1 To 10 'Replace 1 and 10 with your first and last row of hyperlinks
        wlink = Cells(i, 2).Value 'My links are in column B, hence "2". Change this to fit your sheet (1 for column A, 3 for Column C, etc.)
        ie.Navigate wlink
        While ie.busy = True 'Allow the website to load the image (wait for 1 second if browser is busy)
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Wend
        fname = ie.Document.Title
        fname = Replace(fname, "/", "_")
        fname = Replace(fname, " - Google Disk", "") 'Removing the additional text from the filename
        fname = lpath + fname
        Cells(i, 2).Value = fname 'Replaces the hyperlink with the local filename
        Cells(i, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2).Value
    Next i
    ie.Quit
End Sub
```

This should solve your problem - let me know if you have any troubles.

**PS: Remember to set the `lpath` variable to the folder path where you have the local images**